# Applying .get() function On a Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation

I am working on sample dataset to retrieve location information from address(some details are changed for identification purpose);

```
temp2=pd.DataFrame({'USER_ID':[1268,12345,4204,4208], 'IP_ADDR':['142.176.00.83','24.000.63.230','187.178.252.99','187.178.250.99']})
```

My goal is to get Lattitude and longitude information using the `ip2geotools`  python package. The syntax is follows;

```
!pip install ip2geotools
response = DbIpCity.get(a, api_key='free')
json_file = response.to_json()
```

where `a='142.176.00.83'`. Then we get a JSON file like this;

```
'{"ip_address": "142.176.00.83", "city": "Charlotte", "region": "Prince Edward", "country": "CA", "latitude": 46.2, "longitude": -63.131}'
```

I am trying to apply the function on an entire pandas  series (vectored form) and retrieve latitude and longitude as two different columns. Here is my attempt:

```
temp2['y'] = temp2['IP_ADDR'].apply(lambda x: DbIpCity.get(x, api_key='free'))
```

But it seems it doesn't like this syntax, `InvalidRequestError:` .

But if I execute the code on one string it works fine;

```
DbIpCity.get('2401:4900:40cc:e9cc:6ccc:348e:4020:2593', api_key='free')

ip2geotools.models.IpLocation(2401:4900:40cc:e9cc:6ccc:348e:4020:2593)
```

On the other hand, if there are no quotes then it fails;

```
DbIpCity.get(2401:4900:40cc:e9cc:6ccc:348e:4020:2593, api_key='free')
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But my data doesn't have quotes around it. If I try to add the quotes it fails;

```
i=str(2401:4900:40cc:e9cc:6ccc:348e:4020:2593)
print("'"+str(i)+"'")      
    i=str(2401:4900:40cc:e9cc:6ccc:348e:4020:2593)
          ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can I kindly get some help on how to vectorize this operation and retrieve fields from JSON file. thanks

Comment: You need to use quotes whenever you write an IP address in your code, otherwise you'll get invalid syntax because of the colons. Writing quotes around an IP address makes it a string, so you don't need to use the str() function.

Comment: Also if your original problem was solved, please mark my answer as accepted and ask a new question if you have a new problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is raised by ip2geotools, not pandas, because the IP format is improper. Code works for me after changing IP's to have only single 0's in each part.

i.e. change `'24.000.63.230'` to `'24.0.63.230'`

You can apply this fix to your dataframe using:

```
temp2['IP_ADDR'] = temp2['IP_ADDR'].replace(r'\.0+\.', '.0.', regex=True)
```

Comment: appreciate your feedback. Is there a way to vectorize this operation?Can you kindly share complete answer?

Comment: Updated answer with solution for your dataframe

Comment: Appreciate your feedback. it seems multiple zeroes is not the issue.  I did add an example to my question.